# Select DISTINCT from two columns in t-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select, distinct

Say, if I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl (ID INT, Type UNIQUEIDENTIFIER)
INSERT tbl VALUES
(1, N'D9D09D5B-AF63-484C-8229-9762B52972D0'),
(2, N'D9D09D5B-AF63-484C-8229-9762B52972D6'),
(3, N'D9D09D5B-AF63-484C-8229-9762B52972D9'),
(3, N'D9D09D5B-AF63-484C-8229-9762B52972D2'),
(4, N'D9D09D5B-AF63-484C-8229-9762B52972D0')
```

and I need to select distinct ID columns but also whatever the Type column value that is associated with it. If I do the following:

```
select distinct id, type from tbl
```

It returns the whole table when I need only this:

```
1, N'D9D09D5B-AF63-484C-8229-9762B52972D0'
2, N'D9D09D5B-AF63-484C-8229-9762B52972D6'
3, N'D9D09D5B-AF63-484C-8229-9762B52972D9'
4, N'D9D09D5B-AF63-484C-8229-9762B52972D0'
```

I know it must be something simple, but what am I missing here?

Comment: So why did you take type value as `N'D9D09D5B-AF63-484C-8229-9762B52972D9'` where id = 3?

Comment: It was the first in the list.

Comment: Updated the answer and also the fiddle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per you comment you need to want to select first type in the list. So you can achieve this by using subquery like this:

```
SELECT id, (SELECT TOP 1 type FROM tbl a WHERE id = b.id)
FROM tbl b GROUP BY id
```

## [*See this SQLFiddle*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/96807/6)

Comment: Thanks, but what if the Type field is not an int but uniqueidentifier?

Comment: @ahmd0 Suppose type contains `A,B,C,D,E` then which value will you take from `C`&`D`?.

Comment: The type can contain values such as N'D9D09D5B-AF63-484C-8229-9762B52972D0'

Comment: @ahmd0 Edit your question and update create table definition and desired output.

Comment: Thanks, bro. I'm learning all this stuff, so just from curiousity, why can't I do: SELECT id, type FROM tbl GROUP BY id. Or I guess I'm confusing what GROUP BY does?

Comment: You can't do it like this. You can do like this `SELECT ID, TYPE FROM tbl GROUP BY ID,TYPE` Learn more about [`GROUP BY` here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx)

Comment: Yeah, I tried reading it but it was too difficult to understand ... well, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2):

```
select id, min(type) from tbl group by id
```